# How to pass the parameter in InertiaJS?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, frontend, inertiajs

I got a problem with how the URL appeared in the browser after I have set up a route and call it through Inertia .

The route `Route::get('/blogs/{post}', [BlogController::class, 'show']);` from `web.php` works fine if I input it manually, e.g. `localhost:3000/blogs/1`.

However, the `<Link>` would not work if I click the button, instead the URL is displayed as `http://localhost:3000/blogs/?post=1`. Is there anyway to remove the `?post=` from the URL?

Below is my Vue component displaying the `<Link>`

```
<div class="wrapper" v-if="blogs.length">
          <div class="blog" v-for="blog in blogs" :key="blog">
            <Link href="/blogs/" :data="{post:blog.id}">
              <small>posted by: {{ blog.id }}</small>
              {{ blog.title }}
            </Link>
            <button type="button" @click="destroy($event, blog.id)">
                Delete post
            </button>
          </div>
</div>
```

Note that I am following the docs from https://inertiajs.com/links.

Comment: You can use Ziggy in order to uses the routes, name your route then uses `:href="$route('posts.show', { post: 1 });"` https://inertiajs.com/routing

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier I tried using Ziggy but I ended up messing up the entire routing... I will try again (lol).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're passing the `data` prop. This will cause the object to be passed as the payload of the request. That's why it is ending up appended to the route as a query string.

```js
// change this
<Link href="/blogs/" :data="{post:blog.id}">

// to this
<Link href="/blogs/your-blog-id-goes-here" >
```